# async loading of new page and change link

Tags: javascript

I have been wondering how those guys have achieved their async page loading. Even though they don't reload the page, the link is changing. The page change is so smooth, it doesn't even look like they are loading anything. Neither it's showing any files loaded in chrome Network tab.

source: http://activetheory.net

Comment: _"Neither it's showing any files loaded in chrome Network tab"_ You need to open the network tab and then reload the page, to see all the requests. And yeah, there are a lot of them.

Comment: @blex there is a lot of resources loading at the beginning. But not when you change the page ... of course when you refresh a page, it will load resources

Comment: @TomaszGolinski I'm seeing new requests every time I click on something.

Comment: perhaps they are using pushState - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: @blex the only new request I see is from googleanalytics (collect?.....)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: @TomaszGolinski I see images and CSS files loading along with googleanalytics

Answer (score 0):

Most of the resources for their page are loaded at the first connection and managed in the style.css and data.js files loaded from AWS.

You can see those files loaded in you debugger console. The "async" behaviour is just a client side effect. Actually, it is not even an asynchroneous connection that's taking place.